# Android xml phone number in keyboard restriction

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, phone-number, input-type-file

Hi in my project i have a edit text box, where i want the user to enter his phone number, I need it in a format like +0000000000 no need to allow - or any other symbols. I need to restrict the user while entering in keyboard. I have implemented the regular expression for validation for this format and I am using android:inputType="phone" is there any other input Type is available or can i customize it in any way. Looking for help pls...

Answer (score 1):

Try it android:digits="+0123456789"

Answer (score 0):

**try this::**

```
android:inputType="number"
```

it allow user to enter only integer value